# get average value from sqlite database using nodejs and sqlite 3

Tags: node.js, express, sqlite

I have the following code, where I am trying to insert a record into SQLite database and trying to read from it.

```
 let stmt = db.prepare('INSERT INTO ratings(post_id, rating) VALUES (?, ?)')
    stmt.run(1,4);
    stmt.finalize()
 // code above works succefully
 let stmt2 = db.prepare(`SELECT AVG(rating) as avg_rating FROM ratings WHERE post_id = ?`)
   stmt2.run(1, (err, row) => {
        console.log(row) // here it returns undefined
    });

    stmt2.finalize()
```

But as I have mentioned it in the commented code the insertion works properly but while reading, the row and err is null and undefined when I console log them. where did I went wrong?

**Basically how do I retrieve the result of an aggregate function from sqlite in nodejs ?**

Comment: Wouldn't you want the `get` or `all` method to _select_ data?

Comment: I think I need to use get. Any idea how can I do this?

Comment: Here's a place to start: [Querying Data in SQLite Database](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-nodejs/query/)